# How do you find fibonacci numbers in a range between two integers?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I am creating a c++ code to output a fibonacci sequence between two numbers. Part of my code is meant to output if there are no fibonacci numbers in between two integers. For example, if a user put in 9 and 12, the code would output "None". But if the integers were like 0 to 10, it would output 0,1,1,2,3,5,8. Below is my code currently.

How would I fix this code to output if there were not any fibonacci numbers in the given range? Right now, this code will read (for the range 9 to 12),

NoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNone

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main(){
int high, low;

cout<< "Enter two integers: ";
cin>>low>>high;

int i=0;
int f1=0, f2 = 1,f3 = 1;
while (f1 <= high)

{

   
        f1 = f2;

        f2 = f3;

        f3 = f1 + f2;
    
    i++;
    
     if (f1>=low && f1<=high){
        
        cout<<setw(10)<<f1;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"None";
    }

    if (i != 0 && ((i % 6) == 0)){
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
    
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This `if (f1 >= low){` (the first one) says only calculate a fibonacci number if `f1` is larger than the lower bound. Is that really what you want? Surely what you want to do is calculate fibonacci numers but only **print** them if they are greater than the lower bound. That what the second `if (f1>=low)` does, the first one can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

So, your calculation of Fibonacci numbers is correct.

But you need to decouple things.

1. Calculation of Fibaoncci numbers
2. Range check and then print, if in range
3. Check, if something was printed at all. If not, then show message

You should also use the correct data type. Fibonacci numbers grow rapidly. So, a 64bit dataype like `unsigned long long` would be strongly recommended.

And, even then, only 93 possible Fibancci numbers exist for a 64bit value. (Binet's formula).

A possible soultion could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using ull = unsigned long long;

int main() {

    std::cout << "Inclusive range scan in Fibanocci series\n\nEnter the lower boundary and then the upper boundary:\n";
    
    // Get input values and check, if they are valid
    if (ull low{}, high{}; (std::cin >> low >> high) && (low < high)) {

        // Remeber, if some Fibonacci number could be found
        bool somethingWasFound{false};

        // Initial values of Fibonacci series
        ull f1{ 0 }, f2{ 1 }, f3{ 1 };

        // Search all Fibonacci numbers
        while (f1 <= high) {

            // If Fibonacci number is in range, the print it
            // No need to compare with high. This will be done in while statement
            if (f1 >= low) {
                std::cout << f1 << ' ';
                somethingWasFound = true;
            }
            // Calculate next Fibonacci number
            f1 = f2;
            f2 = f3;
            f3 = f1 + f2;
        }
        if (not somethingWasFound)
            std::cout << "\n\nNo Fibonacci number found in range: " << low << ',' << high << '\n';

    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error: invalid input\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

To be compiled with C++17 enabled. Set your compiler flags respectively.